# How to run .exe file which is stored in war file?

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

How to get the path of that exe file in my java class .That exe file is stored in war file(that war file is deployed in server)?

Comment: So how to run or how to get path?

Comment: @Antonioss i want  to run that .exe

Comment: Is this some kind of embedded server which needs unpack the war file and run the exe?

Comment: Why not to search the server for the .exe file, then print the path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I locate a non-Java resource in a WAR at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974837/how-can-i-locate-a-non-java-resource-in-a-war-at-runtime)

Comment: @flyer actually i don't have idea on that server . thinking that it may not unpack that war file.

Comment: @NRB So you provide a WAR file, and you want put an exe file inside which will be executed during deployment by 3rd party server?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot launch `.exe` file directly from `war` as Windows don't have access to content of war package. You would have to extract it first (eg to `temp` dir) and then invoke new proces from there.

As for path, you can alwas get  `URL` to resources via classloader. `ClassLoader#getResource` and `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream` is what you need.

Comment: how to extract that exe to temp dir .

Comment: Get you file as stream (getResourceAsStream method) and store it's contents as file somewhere. Google for `getResourceAsStream` and `copy stream into file`.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach could work:

1) Prepare full path of your executable:

```
 ServletContext context = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/executable");
```

2) Execute like you would normally do it:

```
String[] cmd = { fullPath /*[...] arguments */};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```