# java, execute exe from WAR in java code

Tags: java, external-process

In my war, I have file `exe` in `WEB-INF\classes\`

How can I execute this file in Java code (How can I specify path to this file) ?

```
command = " ? ";
Process x = p.exec(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te following approach could work:

1) Prepare full path of your executable:

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/executable");
```

2) Execute like you would normally do it:

```
String[] cmd = { fullPath /*[...] arguments */};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```

This is a simplified example; you may also want to read more about [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: ok, thanks, but I have new other problems, resolved in another way

Comment: Depends on where you use it and how. If that's a test server or predefined infrastructure, and this is an easy way to automate (maybe temporal solution) -- why not. Otherwise I would agree that 'it's a bad idea' and you should consider moving platform-specific executables out of war.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad idea. Imagine simply fact that your .war packege should run on almost any server (".war is platform independend") and your .exe file is compiled just for one architecture.

Better should be execute your .exe as external program just for separate platform independent and platform dependent part. Then in java you can test operating system and on this basis run desired externel programm.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188520/1196670) link with similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do find a file's real location inside a web app is to use the ServletContext.getRealPath (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))

You can access that object from the session...